# Set tiny custom screen resolution on Windows

Tags: windows, screen, resolution

I have a tiny LED screen (64 x 48 pixels) connected to the DVI port of my graphic cards.

How can i extend my windows desktop, setting a custom resolution to 64x48 ?
 (Windows does not offer lower resolution than 640 x 480)

On the web, I only found tutorials for beginner. Do you know any software who can do that ?